# google cloud authenticated endpoint call by web through HTTP

Tags: api, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created my endpoint backend on google cloud, 
and I'm trying to make it authenticated API,

here are the steps I followed :

1. on cloud console I generated a web application OAuth client ID.
2. I added my client ID to the backend source code, I followed this example :
   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/backend/main.py

added my client ID (that was generated when i created the new oauth client id credentials ) in the following variable :

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = 'replace this with your web client application ID'
ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID
ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS = [
               WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, IOS_CLIENT_ID,
               endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID]
```

then I added this variable in the @endpoints.api decorator :

```
@endpoints.api(
allowed_client_ids=ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS,
```

my questions :

1. Is my backend API code ready ? or I'm missing something else?
2. can I generate web client ID for android devices and make them to authenticate to the API through HTTP requests instead of using android client ID credentials and generating client library?
3. I'm tried to send an HTTP request and added basic authorization in the header, I added the client ID and the client secret in the authentication but it gives me 401 (invalid token ), if this is an incorrect request, can anyone give me an example of how my request should look like?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on what you mean by ready.
2. You don't need to use the client library, but for auth to work, you have to use the client ID to generate an auth token to inject into any HTTP requests you make to the API. The client library does this for you, but it wouldn't be too hard to do it yourself.
3. The client ID and secret aren't what go in the header. You use the client ID to generate the auth token, which goes in the header. See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_android#configuring_your_android_client_to_provide_credentials).

Comment: i checked all the documents , but they are all taking about how to make my app to access user data through oAuth , however this is not what i want , i want my frontend android app to access my backend data directly , but i need this process to be authenticated , i want to go with generating auth token myself, how can i do that ? can you give me a document that guide me through this ?